# Calculating number of discernible colors in CIE La*b* space

Tags: color

How can Lab space be easily splitted into unity cubes and determined number of cubes that colours of certain image occupy?

Comment: Sounds like an interesting question, but do you have any code to share with us ? And last, but not least are you sure this question is about Mathematica ?

Comment: Yes, Mathematica  10 is dealing with colour independent spaces like CIE Lab and CIE XYZ and introduces new functions like: ChromaticityPlot3D["LCH", "LAB", Mesh -> Full, MeshStyle -> Black]